# How to check if file exists on remote linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, filesystems, remote-access

I'm trying to check if file exists in Python / Linux.

My local machine (which I ssh from) is: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server.
The target machine (which I ssh to) is: Amazon Linux, centos rhel fedora.

I've tried the following CMD:

```
ssh -qnx [host] "test /path/to/file.txt && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Not'"
```

But it always returns 'Exists', also on files that do not exists.

This CMD also always return exists:

```
ssh host test -f "/path/to/file.txt" && echo found || echo not found
```

As well as this one:

```
if ssh [host] test -e "/path/to/file.txt" ; then echo found ; else echo not found ; fi
```

I've also tried:

```
ssh -q [host] [[ -f /path/to/file.txt ]] && echo "File exists" || echo "File does not exist";
```

But it says: zsh: bad pattern: [[

I need a simple CMD, one that I can later use in python with `os.system(cmd)`, and receive the answer of yes or no.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: `"test /path/to/file.txt && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Not'"` Shouldn't that be `test -f`? With that fixed it works for me.

Comment: It also returns "found" for non-existing files for me. I suspect my local machine is behaving different from regular linux.

Comment: `ssh -qnx user@host "test -e /path/to/file && echo exists || echo not"`. You are missing `-e` or `-f` in your `test` command.

Comment: Or, `ssh -qnx user@host "test -e /path/to/file" && echo exists || echo not`

Comment: ssh -qnx user@host "test -e /path/to/file && echo exists || echo not" - it worked, if you want to add it as an answer and I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
USE_IP='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no remote-machine-username@remote-machine-host/IP'

FILE_NAME=/home/user/file.txt

SSH_PASS='sshpass -p remote-machine-password here...'

if $SSH_PASS ssh $USE_IP stat $FILE_NAME \> /dev/null 2\>\&1
        then
                echo "File exists on remote machine"
        else
                echo "File does not exist on remote machine"

fi
```

Install [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) on your machine to work it.

Comment: I am looking for a CMD that I can later use in a python code with os.system, this is too complex